# Describe someone who is a specific type of annoying

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests

(sorry for bad title, will accept edit of better one)

There's a specific type of person who my friends and I find annoying, but we don't know the word(s) to describe them.

The closest I can get to:
It's that feeling that you get around someone who goes on and on about their "trip to Cambodia" (or wherever), and about "how impactful it was", and about how "we should all try to live more simple lives, man".

Most sitcoms have had an episode where this character/trope occurs (The yak in Zootopia, for example).

It's kind of like "social justice warrior", but that's not quite right either. Does anyone have the term for this person?

My working terms (made up, obviously):

- Round-trip philosopher
- Socialist hipster
- Sarah McLaughlin sympathizer (a joke)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## *Sanctimonious*

A good adjective to use might be *sanctimonious*:

> - pretending to be morally better than other people
>
>   <sub>-- [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sanctimonious)</sub>
> - *[derogatory]* Making a show of being morally superior to other people.
>
>   <sub>-- [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sanctimonious)</sub>

Perhaps a good phrase to describe the kind of person you're talking about would be a *sanctimonius traveller*?

Comment: i REALLY like that... except one thing. Instead of "pretending", what if they "believe" it?

(The difference being how they see themselves vs how they project themselves)

Comment: @goodguy5 I think (?) "sanctimonious" can also be used to refer to people who believe in their own moral superiority. I don't really associate the word with pretence or dishonesty.

Comment: Alright, I think I've settled on using "Sanctimonious", but "Traveler" is still missing something for me. I may think on it and decide to check your answer, anyway. I'm trying to find something that indicates less that they travel (present tense) and more that they travelED (past tense).

Comment: I've decided on "Sanctimonious Sympathizer". I might still look for shorter words (nine syllables!), but this is a good starting point. Related: look up "Pecksniffian", which I found searching for synonyms of sanctimonious.

Answer (score 1):

## *Ostentatious*

My first thought when I saw the question was [*ostentatious*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ostentatious):

> - displaying wealth, knowledge, etc., in a way
>     that is meant to attract attention, admiration, or envy
> - marked by or fond of conspicuous or vainglorious
>     and sometimes pretentious display
>
>   — [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ostentatious)

Answer (score 0):

## *Over the top*

How about *over the top*?

From The Free Dictionary:

> [**over the top**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/over+the+top):
> outrageously overdone; too extreme; excessively expressive or
> dramatic